# change event selector of delegated event dynamically

Tags: jquery

I would like to change 'on the fly' selector of a delegated event.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm8yK/)

For example,

*i use this HTML:*

```
<div id="div1">DIV1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV2</div>    
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

*i delegate a click event for **all DIVs**:*

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function () {
    $("#result").append(this.id + ' DIV click\r\n');
});
```

Later, i need to ***unbound a particular DIV***. I could bound a new delegated event excluding this particular DIV and unbinding previous delegated event. However, in my case, i would like to keep previous event as it and just change the selector of this event, meaning, change `event.selector` of delegated event on the fly.

This is the ***event***:

```
var delegatedEvent = $._data(document, "events").click;
```

So trying to ***exclude a DIV*** by targeting its ***ID attribute*** (class, etc...) **works**, i can use e.g to exclude `#div2`:

```
delegatedEvent[0].selector += ":not(#div2)";  // => selector == 'div:not(#div2)'
```

For some reason, i cannot target element using specific attribute, i need to ***use index of element***:

```
var indexDiv2 = $(delegatedEvent[0].selector).index($("#div2")); // => 1
```

Now trying to exclude #div2 using its ***index doesn't work***:

```
delegatedEvent[0].selector += ":not(:eq("+indexDiv2 +"))";  // => selector == 'div:not(:eq(1))'
```

Looks like matched set is reevaluated (???), if i use `#div1` ***index (0)***, this will ***exclude all DIVs***.

I'm stuck here, needing to use index to target specific DIV but cannot use it to modify a delegated event selector.

**Any idea how to fix it or any known reason for this unexpected behaviour?**

PS: i could use custom `data-*` attribute (data-index) but still wondering why using `:eq()` doesn't work...

Comment: Would there not only be one `div` in the pool from which the `delegatedEvent[0].selector` is looking from, since only one `div` has an event fired from? Thus `:eq(0)` and `:first` being always true?

Comment: but using: `$(document).on("click", "div:not(:eq(1))", handler)` exclude second DIV, so why not by changing event selector property? I was wondering selector "div:not(:eq(1))" to be reevaluated at each call and it seems to be the case

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle it with a dynamic class ?

```
$(document).on("click", "div:not(.exclude)", function () {
    $("#result").append(this.id + ' DIV click\r\n');
});
```

And just add the class `exclude` to the elements you want ? When you want it.

Comment: it's similar to using data-* attribute but will give less complex and more performant selector, so it's quite a simple and efficient idea.

Comment: Just one thing, i still need it to be dynamic as i don't know in advance which elements will be unbound or not, this is following user interraction, so your idea works but should be something like that instead, e.g: `delegatedEvent[0].selector += ":not(.exclude_"+delegatedEvent[0].guid+")";`

Comment: The idea was to keep the selector fixed, and just add the class dynamically to the elements you want once you get that info.. If you can give some info on how/when you decide to add something to the excluded list it would help

Comment: But an element must be unbound to a specific handler and only this handler. This element can be bound to more than one delegated event, so i really need to be as more as possible specific in selector choice. This is quite off topic but what i need is to be able to suspend/resume event of specific type and for specific elements, even delegated ones. I'm currently testing solution using class as in my previous comment and for instance gives expected result/behaviour

Comment: In this case you could have a different `class` to use for each delegated event.. It is much simpler and easier to maintain. Especially if you want to exclude more than one elements from a delegated event handler.. If on the other hand you use delegated events for single element targeting.. that you should bind directly to them..

Comment: i should have said this is to be used as a widget which can be loaded after DOM and events are rendered. I'm not binding events myself.